# VisualStudio 2010 - Dll error: __vcrt_cleanup_type_info_names

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, dll, opencv3.1

I am using OpenCV 3.1 with Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 64 bits. I have rebuilt OpenCV by means of Cmake recently and it appears the next error when I try to compile:

> No se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento 
>   __vcrt_cleanup_type_info_names en la biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos VCRUNTIME140D.dll

I am using

- opencv_world310d.dll
- opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll

I didn't have this problem when I compiled the same code with the official version of OpenCV 3.0. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that you're using the runtime for Visual Studio 2015 (vc14). Double check your properties

Comment: Please do not post image of text.  Post text as text.

Comment: @Miki I am using the .lib files included in vc10 so I think that this is right, no?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten it to work after rebuilt OpenCV with the version 3.0 using Cmake. It seems that version 3.1 is not very stable yet. Thanks!